# SCVMM PowerShell commands not working in Task Scheduler when account is not logged in

Tags: powershell, virtual-machine, scheduled-tasks, system-center

I am trying to run a script with the Task Scheduler.
It works just fine when the user is logged in, but when I try to run it when the user is not logged in, the command `Get-SCVirtualMachine` returns null.

The script does run, but just that command doesnt return any value when I am running it without the service account being logged in.

Of course I have the "Run wether user is logged on or not" flag set to true. And as I said, the script gets executed, just that SCVMM cmdlet isn't working.

Comment: Either have the scheduled task run as the service account, or get the required permissions for access to SCVMM assigned to your own account. Besides, this is a question for [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/).

Comment: the scheduled task is run as a service account as i said. And he has the Permissions to use SCVMM.. it works if i logon to the server once and then start the task job. But it doesnt if i wasnt logged on since the last restart.

Answer (score 0):

The Solution was to add the service account as a local administrator. Somehow i totally forgot that. Therefore it could'nt load the needed PS Modules.